# How to send a custom event from vf page to lwc

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am trying to send an custom event from vf page to LWC. But it is not working.Please tell what am i doing it wrong

```
if(event.ctrlKey && event.key=='u'){

                    openTagmanager(row.data.Id);
                    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("hello", {
                    detail: { name: "John" },
                    bubbles: true,
                    composed: true,
                    }));
                    event.preventDefault();
            }
```

In the parent LWC

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.template.addEventListener('hello', this.handleFocuse.bind(this));
}

handleFocuse(event){
    console.log('gettit')
}
```

I cannot work with LMS as I am using vf page

Comment: Could you add more context ? Code ?
You talk about parent LWC so where is the child ?
Could you share a bit how you add the LWC in the VF ?
I don't understand why you talk about LMS. Communicating between components in the page and LMS are two different things. Could you explain what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `connectedCallback` instead of `constructor` as component will not be in DOM yet in constructor.

Here is a [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom) on lifecycle hooks.

Comment: I tried adding that.But still not working

Comment: How to pass an event from vf page to LWC?